# Trigger Sonar Jenkins job from another Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I want to create a process in Jenkins when one job is building it should internally call another job that is generating a SONAR report for the same code pull request.

When I am trying to call API to trigger Jenkins job automatically.

```
https://jenkins.com/job/DPNew/job/xyz/buildWithParameters?token=DW&FROM_HASH=195c8df91791768f3098ce260eb2dd8728&REPO_NAME=_python&PROJECT_KEY=%7Eabc&EMAIL=abc@gmail.com&FROM_BRANCH_NAME=feature%2FDO-451&TO_BRANCH_NAME=Port-2.7&PR_ID=622"
```

I am getting below error in response.

```
content: "<html><head><body style='background-color:white; 
color:white;'>\n\n\nAuthentication required\n<!--\nYou are authenticated as: anonymous\nGroups that you are in:\n  \nPermission you need to have (but didn't): 
hudson.model.Hudson.Read\n ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead\n ... which is implied by: 
hudson.model.Hudson.Administer\n-->\n\n</body></html>
```

I have already created Jenkins API token in 'user -> configure'

Edit 1:
The first Jenkin job is triggered by a pull request from Bitbucket, and the UI in bitbucket shows if the build is successful and if the build is a success it shows a sonar report.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark as correct or provide more details

Comment: @itay I have added some details in question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of API call, use [job](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/), this will also make it so you can use paramers from your sonar report job and display them here/use them.

example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage_name') {
            steps {
                build job: 'JOB_NAME'
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Or with parameters:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage_name') {
            steps {
                build job: 'JOB_NAME_HERE', propagate: true, parameters:
                [
                    [
                        $class: 'StringParameterValue',
                        name: 'STRING_NAME_HERE',
                        value: "STRING_VALUE_HERE"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
     }
}
```

`propagate: true` means that the original job will fail if JOB_NAME_HERE fails.